# Referencing a custom class in ASP.NET web application

Tags: asp.net, class, master-pages

So I ran into a problem when converting my website to a web application. I have a MasterPage that used to inherit a custom class called MasterParent. When i try to reference it now, it doesn't recognize it at all.

Both of the files are inside the main application folder. Some example code is below:

MasterPage.master.cs

```
public partial class MasterPage : MasterParent
{
}
```

MasterParent.cs (That cant be inherited from the above code)

```
namespace PortfolioApplication
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for MasterContent
    /// </summary>
    public abstract partial class MasterParent : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        #region "Navigation Buttons"

        protected void btnPortfolio_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Server.Transfer("Portfolio.aspx");
        }
        protected void btnHome_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Server.Transfer("Default.aspx");
        }
        protected void btnContact_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Server.Transfer("Contact.aspx");
        }
        protected void btnResume_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Server.Transfer("Resume.aspx");
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

Am I missing something very simple or what am I doing wrong?

Comment: MasterPage.master.cs has a `using PortfolioApplication;` or is declared to be in the same namespace, I presume?  I'm also curious as to why these are partial classes, although that may not be relevant.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was when I imported all of my classes from the webpage into the application. The website that i referred to for this transfer said to drag and drop the files in. I had to recreate each file manually and copy the code over from the previous project in order for it to be referenced.

Answer (score 0):

After copying the files from the Website into the Web Application, IIRC you also need to right-click the new project and select Convert To Web Application (see also: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983476(VS.100).aspx).  This causes the markup files to be converted from using the CodeFile attribute (which compiles on the fly at runtime) to using CodeBehind (which compiles at design time - a key difference between Website and Web Application projects).

The Convert To Web Application command will also rename your App_Code to Old_App_Code so those files will also be compiled at design time.  In VS2012, there were some changes so that content in App_Code can be used at design time as well, but previously App_Code was ignored by VS in a Web Application project.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. I recreated all the classes and I'm not getting the same error but I am still getting an error. Any chance you have any idea of what is going on? I created a new thread for it because it is not the same problem. You can see the code and error here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13183923/masterpage-master-inheriting-from-another-class-that-inherits-mastpage