# MasterPage.master inheriting from another class that inherits MastPage

Tags: asp.net, inheritance, master-pages

I have my master page inheriting from a class called MasterParent. During compilation, I get an error as following:

Compilation Error:

Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.

Compiler Error Message: ASPNET: Make sure that the class defined in this code file matches the 'inherits' attribute, and that it extends the correct base class (e.g. Page or UserControl).

Source Error:

```
Line 8:  namespace PortfolioApplication
Line 9:  {
Line 10:     public partial class MasterPage : MasterParent
Line 11:     {
Line 12:     }
```

My code:
MasterParent.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace PortfolioApplication
{
    public abstract class MasterParent : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        #region "Navigation Buttons"

        protected void btnPortfolio_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Server.Transfer("Portfolio.aspx");
        }
        protected void btnHome_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Server.Transfer("Default.aspx");
        }
        protected void btnContact_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Server.Transfer("Contact.aspx");
        }
        protected void btnResume_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Server.Transfer("Resume.aspx");
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

MasterPage.master.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace PortfolioApplication
{
    public class MasterPage : MasterParent 
    {

    }
}
```

Also:
I just tried changing my code in the MasterParent.cs for the class header:

```
public partial class MasterPage: System.WEb.UI.MasterPage and i am getting the same error about inheritence.
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have the `partial` modifier on every definition of `MasterPage : MasterParent`.

Comment: Had it in there before. I removed it trying every possible scenario and its still a no go.

Comment: Hmm, try doing it from scratch with a single *.cs file and single, non-partial classes deriving from MasterPage.